# set<>* da segmentation fault

Tags: c++, punteros, set

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo de minimizacion de dfa, con lo que tengo una clase dfa con el siguiente atributo:

```
vector<set<estado*>* >grupos;
```

como se puede ver es un vector que guarda los punteros a `set`'s de punteros de estados.

Cuando tengo que incluir/crear nuevos `set`'s no hay problema:

```
grupos.push_back(new set<estado*>);
grupos.push_back(new set<estado*>);

for(int i=0;i<grafo.size();i++){

    if(grafo[i]->get_aceptado()==true)
        grupos[0]->insert(grafo[i]);
    else
        grupos[1]->insert(grafo[i]);
}
```

Total se van haciendo operaciones hasta que llego a lo siguiente:

```
    if(continuar==true){
        grupos.push_back(new set<estado*>);
        grupos.back()->insert(A);
        grupos[grupito]->erase(A);
    }
```

Idea de esta seccion de codigo es crear un nuevo `set`, y meter ahi el nodo/estado que se esta evaluando y, quitar el mismo de donde estaba anteriormente.

El codigo me permite perfectamente las dos primeras operaciones, es decir , crear el nuevo set e insertar el estado en el mismo, lo que me da fallo es intentar eliminar el estado del set anterior, para evitar duplicaciones.

Se que la variable `grupito` no es el problema, porque es la posicion que representa al `set` inicial.

el metodo completo es :

```
void buscar_grupo_nuevo(estado* A,int grupito){

    int next=-1,next_a=-1;
    char cadena_tran_a;
    bool continuar=true;
    bool skip=false;
    int destino=-1;
    for(int j=0;j<grupos.size() && continuar==true;j++){


        for(int i=0;i<A->get_ntrans() && skip==false ;i++){

            cadena_tran_a=A->get_trans(i).get_cadena();
            next_a=A->search_next_state(cadena_tran_a);
            next_a=buscar_estado(next_a);

            next=(*grupos[j]->begin())->search_next_state(cadena_tran_a);
            next=buscar_estado(next);

            if(next!=next_a || A->get_aceptado()!=(*grupos[j]->begin())->get_aceptado() || next==grupito){
                skip=true;
            }
        }

        if(skip==true)
            skip=false;

        else{
            continuar=false;
            destino=j;
        }


    }


    cout<<"Estado: "<<A->get_id()<<"  continuar: "<<continuar<<"   , destino: "<<destino<<endl;
    cout<<"grupos size: "<<grupos.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"grupito: "<<grupito<<endl;
    cout<<"(void*)grupos[grupito]"<<(void *)grupos[grupito]<<endl;;


    if(continuar==true){
        grupos.push_back(new set<estado*>);
        grupos.back()->insert(A);
        //grupos[grupito]->erase(A);
    }   
    /*
    if (continuar==false){

        grupos[destino]->insert(A);
        grupos[grupito]->erase(A);
    }


    */
}
```

Haciendo pruebas he visto que el error esta en algun lugar de este bucle que esta en el metodo que llama a `busar_grupo_nuevo`, como se ve, he intentado llamar a `erase` y funciona, pero con el iterador que crea el bucle no....

```
    //grupos[i]->erase(grupos[i]->begin());        <---- esto funciona y elimina el elemento
    for(set<estado*>::iterator j = grupos[i]->begin(); j != grupos[i]->end() ; j++){
        if(j!=grupos[i]->begin()){
            for(int h=0;h<transiciones.size();h++){
                if(destino[h] != buscar_estado( (*j)->search_next_state(transiciones[h]) ) ){
                    //cout<<"direccion de puntero: "<<(*j)<<endl;
                    //cout<<"direccion del iterador: "<<j<<endl;
                    estado* A=(*j);
                    cout<<"size del grupoL: "<<grupos[i]->size()<<endl;
                    grupos[i]->erase(j);   // <-- este no funciona
                    cout<<"size del grupoL: "<<grupos[i]->size()<<endl;
                    buscar_grupo_nuevo(A,i);
                }
            }
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Pues `grupito` no será el problema ... pero tiene toda la pinta. ¿ Puedes hacer `cout << grupos.size( );`, `cout << grupito;` y `cout << (void *)grupos[grupito];` justo al inicio ese `if( )` y añadir la salida a la pregunta ?

Comment: este es la salida : grupos size: 2
grupito: 0
(void*)grupos[grupito]0x557d63a9b8c0 . Al hacer esto pudo acceder al set `grupos[grupitos]` not??  ,con lo cual no es un problema de acceso a memoria no reservada, ya que no dio segfault, (comente la linea problematica)

Comment: De hecho, tengo un metodo que se encarga de mostrar el contenido de cada set, con lo cual accede a todos las posiciones de grupo, y comentando la linea , lo muestra todo correctamente, solo que , queda el elemento duplicado porque no lo he eliminado del grupo original

Comment: Al hacer eso solo compruebas que no sea `nullptr`. El que muestre una dirección no quiere decir que puedas acceder a ella. Un problema curioso, el tuyo O_o

Comment: gracias supongo jajajaj XD

Comment: Si al comentar esa línea **no da problemas** ... no falla, estás accediendo a memoria que no es tuya. No usas *iteradores* ... realmente curioso :-O

Comment: si quieres pongo el metodo completo, a lo mejor hay algo por ahi ..

Comment: @k1k4ss0, sin ver el resto del código,  lo único que encuentro sospechoso es que al insertar el nuevo conjunto, el contenedor cambia--su tamaño e iteradores que puedas tener en uso.  Lo que yo haría is marcar los que necesitas borrar y usar la expresión idiomática de remove-erase (o remove_if-erase) para eliminar los conjuntos que no necesites--los que hayas marcado.